# Handling SVIX Webhook in Next.js 14 API route via Ngrok

Tags: next.js, webhooks, ngrok, app-router, next.js14

I'm facing an issue where I can't seem to properly receive my Webhooks originating from SVIX in my Next.js 14 app.

I am using Ngrok to forward the requests to my Next.js app running on Local Host. However every HTTP request returns a '308 Permanent Redirect'.

Any ideas on how to fix this ? I simply want to log the response for now.

**Below is my Next.js API route (app/api/recallWebhook/route.js):**

```
import crypto from "crypto";

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const body = await request.json();

    console.log("Webhook received:", body);

    const signingSecret = process.env.DEV_RECALL_WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET;
    console.log("Signing secret:", signingSecret);

    const svixId = request.headers.get("svix-id");
    const svixTimestamp = request.headers.get("svix-timestamp");
    const svixSignature = request.headers.get("svix-signature");

    const signedContent = `${svixId}.${svixTimestamp}.${JSON.stringify(body)}`;
    const secretBytes = Buffer.from(signingSecret.split("_")[1], "base64");

    const computedSignature = crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", secretBytes)
      .update(signedContent)
      .digest("base64");

    const isSignatureValid = svixSignature.split(" ").some((sig) => {
      const [version, signature] = sig.split(",");
      return signature === computedSignature;
    });

    if (!isSignatureValid) {
      return new Response("Invalid signature", { status: 401 });
    }

    console.log("Verified webhook:", body);

    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({
        message: "Webhook received and verified successfully",
      }),
      {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing webhook", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Error processing webhook" }),
      {
        status: 500,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  }
}

export function GET() {
  return new Response("GET method not supported", { status: 405 });
}
```

**This is a snapshot of my Ngrok Server :**

```
Session Status                online
Account                       ******* (Plan: Free)
Version                       3.6.0
Region                        Europe (eu)
Latency                       38ms
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    https://****-***-248-85-9.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:3000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              103     4       0.00    0.01    6.05    149.09

HTTP Requests
-------------

POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
POST /api/recallWebhook/       308 Permanent Redirect
```

**This is the Endpoint URL that I am sending the webhook requests to:**

```
https://****-***-248-85-9.ngrok-free.app/api/recallWebhook/
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seemed to relate to how Next.js handles redirects, I simply had to enforce trailingSlash in my Next Config :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {

  trailingSlash: true,

}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```